# Catch2 with CMake and Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, catch2

I'm trying to setup [Catch2](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2) test framework for a library I have built. I'm using CMake and Visual Studio 2017.

My project structure is:

```
executable-project/
|-- library
      |--include/
      |    |--SUT.h 
      |--src/
      |    |--SUT.cpp
      |--tests/
      |    |--catch.hpp
      |    |--SUTTest.cpp
      |CMakeLists.txt
|include/
|src/
| |--main.cpp
|CMakeLists.txt
```

`SUT.h`, `SUT.cpp` and `SUTTest.cpp` are just testing a factorial function defined based on the [example](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/tutorial.md#writing-tests).

My CMakeLists.txt file in the library is

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)

file(GLOB HEADER_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h")
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")
file(GLOB TEST_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/*.cpp")

add_library(MY_LIBRARY ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES} ${TEST_FILES})

target_include_directories(MY_LIBRARY PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")

source_group("Test Files" FILES ${TEST_FILES})
```

The `SUTTest.cpp` file is:

```
#define CATCH_CONFIG_MAIN

#include "catch.hpp"
#include "SUT.h"

TEST_CASE("Factorials are computed", "[factorial]")
{
    SUT sut;

    REQUIRE(sut.Factorial(0) == 0);
    REQUIRE(sut.Factorial(1) == 1);
    REQUIRE(sut.Factorial(2) == 2);
    REQUIRE(sut.Factorial(3) == 6);
    REQUIRE(sut.Factorial(10) == 3628800);
}
```

The "executable-project" simply makes use of the library (it's the actual application). The `CMakeLists.txt` in that project dynamically links the library to it.

When I build this solution in Visual Studio, build works fine.

However, the test isn't failing despite asserting that the `Factorial(0) == 0`. Also, Visual Studio is not discovering the tests in the tests folder. What I'm trying to achieve are:

1. When I click on Build in Visual Studio, the tests to be run as part of the build.
2. (Optional) to be able for Visual Studio to discover the tests.

EDIT:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)

project("My Project")

file(GLOB HEADER_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h")
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp")

add_subdirectory(library)
add_executable(MY_APP main.cpp ${HEADER_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_include_directories(MY_APP PUBLIC "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
target_link_libraries(MY_APP MY_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: Please share your root level CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @ap-osd I added the root level file as an edit.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I manually test the functionality of the library it's working fine"? Because you also say "the test isn't failing".

Comment: @ap-osd Sorry, that is not relevant. I deleted it. It was before I added the test function I think. Please ignore that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally managed to get Catch2 to work with Visual Studio.

First I downloaded Catch2 release from their GitHub and installed it on my computer using (this is actually documented [here](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/cmake-integration.md)).

```
cmake -Bbuild -S. -DBUILD_TESTING=OFF
cmake --build build/ --target install (Need admin rights)
```

This installs Catch2 in C:\Program Files (x86)\Catch2. Then I copied everything in this install directory to my project's deps/Catch2 folder. Then just add the below to the CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED PATHS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/Catch2")
target_link_libraries(MY_LIBRARY Catch2::Catch2)

include(CTest)
include(Catch)
catch_discover_tests(MY_LIBRARY)
```

This adds the RUN_TESTS project to Visual Studio. When I build this project, my unit tests run. Hope this is helpful to anyone trying to integrate with CMake.

Answer (score 0):

> the test isn't failing despite asserting that the Factorial(0) == 0

You should assert what is true/expected. Then if your written code is wrong, it will fail.

`REQUIRE( Factorial(0) == 1 );` (not `== 0`)

> When I click on Build in Visual Studio, the tests to be run as part of
>   the build.

Within the Visual Studio IDE, the build and run are two separate steps. If you want to sequence it automatically, write a simple `.bat` script which first builds and then runs.

> (Optional) to be able for Visual Studio to discover the tests.

Catch2 has CMake integration which *contains CMake scripts for automatic registration of `TEST_CASE`s in CTest*.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(baz LANGUAGES CXX VERSION 0.0.1)

find_package(Catch2 REQUIRED)
add_executable(foo test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo Catch2::Catch2)

include(CTest)
include(Catch)
catch_discover_tests(foo)
```

See [Catch2 CMake Integration](https://github.com/catchorg/Catch2/blob/master/docs/cmake-integration.md) for details.